# overriding with different return types (generic collections)

Tags: java, generics, collections

Please help me solve the following:

1. class `Cat` must extend `Animal` (keep inheritance);
2. `Animal.getAll()` must return all animals (cats, dogs, etc.) and `Cat.getAll()` must return only cats (don't alter the signature).

I've tried and failed with error `The return type is incompatible with Animal.getAll()` on line 8.

```
class Animal {
    public static List<Animal> getAll() {
        return new ArrayList<Animal>();
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    public static List<Cat> getAll() {
        return new ArrayList<Cat>();
    }
}
```

Comment: paste the codes, how did you invoke the methods.

Comment: Are you really intending the getAll method to be static? Static methods are not overridden with inheritance.

Comment: I haven't even tried to envoke them since I'd got the error just writting those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change line 2 to:

```
public static List<? extends Animal> getAll() {
```

it will work.
See [Java Wildcards in Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html) for more information